# MySQL/Apache redundant server setup

Tags: mysql, apache, wamp, database-replication, server-hardware

I am going to buy two servers shortly which will be exact copies of each other in terms of hardware, software and WAMP setup.

I would like to give my users maximum up-time by having one of the servers as a live backup of the other one.

That is, when the main server fails for whatever reason, all traffic is routed to the backup so users don't notice a thing. When the main server comes back up, any new data that went into the database on the backup server is copied over to the main one.

How can I achieve this without having any inconsistencies with the data? Up-time and data integrity are vital.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is called fail-over cluster. Here is an article how to configure Apache cluster.
Also you have to configure MySQL databases either like a cluster, more information [here](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/). Your task does not fit in one answer as configuration has to be done in terms of your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

For Dual-Master-Single-Writer, see MHA.  It works well, except for "split brain".

For data integrity, never write to more than one Master at a time.

Don't forget to worry about hurricanes, earthquakes, etc.  Your two setups should be in geographically distinct locations.

With only two servers, and with them geographically separated, the network becomes a potential problem.  This could lead to a "Split brain", wherein you can't really tell that one is dead and you need to switch to the other.

Any type of automatic failover will have a few seconds of not-quite-failure.

To talk about "uptime", the common technique is to tell them how many "nines" they get.

See Galera (available through MariaDB or Percona) as perhaps the best (today) HA setup.